# Identifying variable name within function

Tags: r

One of my scripts has a section with repetitive code as in:

```
cat(capture.output(describe(semWellCases$di)),
                file="./output/descriptivestats.txt", 
                sep="\n",append=TRUE)

cat(capture.output(describe(semWellCases$dd)),
                file="./output/descriptivestats.txt", 
                sep="\n",append=TRUE)

cat(capture.output(describe(semWellCases$fas)),
                file="./output/descriptivestats.txt", 
                sep="\n",append=TRUE)
```

This section is aimed at creating a file and appending the stats for each variable to the file. My attempt to make it a function is partially working:

```
descriptiveStats <- function ( vars, filename ) {
  for (i in vars) {
   cat(capture.output(describe(i)),
         file=filename, 
      sep="\n",append=TRUE)
 }
}
```

Which I call with:

```
descriptiveStats(semWellCases[c("di","dd", "fas")], "./output/stats.txt")
```

The problem is the output file has no variable names, they are all listed as `i`, which is the name I used in the for loop:

```
 1  Variables      195  Observations
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
i 
       n  missing distinct     Info     Mean      Gmd      .05      .10 
     195        0       13    0.982    5.574    2.891      2.0      3.0 
     .25      .50      .75      .90      .95 
     4.0      5.0      7.0      9.0      9.3 

Value          2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
Frequency     15    32    37    23    24    20    18    16     5     2     1
Proportion 0.077 0.164 0.190 0.118 0.123 0.103 0.092 0.082 0.026 0.010 0.005

Value         14    28
Frequency      1     1
Proportion 0.005 0.005
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After appending several describe() outputs in a series, it becomes impossible to identify the summaries to the respective variable.

- How can I print the variable name passed to the function before each `describe()` output?

Comment: How are they listed as `i`? is that `stats.txt` problematic since you don't know where it comes from?

Comment: See, third line of the describe output(), there is in `i` there. I want it to be the name of the variable, either `dd`, `fas` or `di`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to loop through the names of the data.frame and print that before printing the output from `describe`

```
descriptiveStats <- function ( vars, filename ) {
    for (i in names(vars)) {
        cat(paste0(i, "\n"), file=filename, append=TRUE)
        cat(capture.output(describe(vars[,i])),
            file=filename, 
            sep="\n",append=TRUE)
    }
}
```

Comment: For a regular data.frame `vars[, i]` or `vars[, i, drop = FALSE]` is pretty safe to use...

Comment: thanks, @RomanLuštrik. may i ask any reason why `'[['` is not preferred?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, `[[` works perfectly fine for data.frames (which are special kind of lists), but using `[` hints that the subsetting object is a data.frame (or a matrix) and not a list per se. Perhaps adds a bit to readability. Feel free to use any paradigm.